# import components into components with vue3, vite and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

having an issue here where i want to be able to see importable vue components while typing in intelliSens:

```js
import VueComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'
```

my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

as you can see i set a alias with `@/*` in paths.

i also added a `shims-vue-d.ts` in the project root like:

```js
declare module "*.vue" {
  import { defineComponent } from "vue";
  const Component: ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>;
  export default Component;
}
```

my `vite.config.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
// import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

issue is, i can import with no problems. but it wont show me the vue files in vscode intelliSens.

some one a idea why? it all looks fine to me.

---

#### Update

this seems to be related to a issue of the [Volar](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar) Extension for Vue.

[Import autocomplete does not suggest components while typing the path](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1304)

Comment: You ask about the wrong thing. It's specific to IDE, not Vite, probably not TS config either